# Adding active class to current slider using {% for %}

Tags: jquery, slider, opencart

Im setting up a custom slider in Opencart 3 based around Bootstrap default carousel.

In my slider.twig file i have the following :

```
    {% for banner in banners %}
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="{{ banner.image }}" alt="{{ banner.title }}" />
      <div class="carousel-caption post_carousel_caption">
        <h1 data-animation="animated fadeInLeft">post page carousel</h1>
        <h2 data-animation="animated fadeInRight">with beautiful animation</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

This then adds the "active" class to every slide, and obviously the slider does not work. How can i add the "active" class to ONLY the current slide in this instance?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `active` class to the first slide

```
{% for key, banner in banners %}
    <div class="item {{ (key == 0)?'active' }}">
      <img src="{{ banner.image }}" alt="{{ banner.title }}" />
      <div class="carousel-caption post_carousel_caption">
        <h1 data-animation="animated fadeInLeft">post page carousel</h1>
        <h2 data-animation="animated fadeInRight">with beautiful animation</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```